# What is next step of $\sum\limits_{a=1}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{b=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{a+b}}{ab(a+b)}$?

Tags: summation, transformation

$$\sum\limits_{a=1}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{b=1}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{c=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{abc(a+b+c)}=\sum\limits_{a=1}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{b=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{a+b}}{ab(a+b)}=\sum\limits_{a=1}^{\infty}?$$

What is the next step?

Comment: What is $H_{a+b}$?

Comment: Harmonic number. Is it not obvious? Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you undo the first step like Hurkyl suggested, you are left with
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{-\log^3(1-x)}{x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{-\log^3(x)}{1-x}\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 0}\int_{0}^{1}-\log^3(x)x^n\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{6}{(n+1)^4}=6\,\zeta(4)=\color{red}{\frac{\pi^4}{15}}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Define

$$ f(x) = \sum_{a=1}^{\infty} \sum_{b=1}^{\infty} \sum_{c=1}^{\infty}  \frac{x^{a+b+c}}{abc(a+b+c)} $$

Then, we have

$$ x f'(x) = \sum_{a=1}^{\infty} \sum_{b=1}^{\infty} \sum_{c=1}^{\infty}  \frac{x^{a+b+c}}{abc} 
= \left( \sum_{a=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^a}{a} \right)
\left( \sum_{b=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^b}{b} \right)\left( \sum_{c=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^c}{c} \right)
\\ = \mathrm{Li}_1(x)^3 = (-\log(1-x))^3$$

where $\mathrm{Li}_1$ denotes a polylogarithm.

Therefore,  you can reduce the problem to the analytic one of determining

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm{Li}_1(x)^3}{x} \, \mathrm{d} x $$

[Wolframa Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20polylog(1,t)%5E3%20%2F%20t%20dt%20for%20t%3D0..1) computes this integral to be $\frac{\pi^4}{15}$. It can also express indefinite integral in terms of higher polylogarithms.

---

Technical note: pay attention to the fact the righthand sums don't converge when $x=1$. However, by analytic continuation, the fact it holds for $|x| < 1$ implies it should also hold on the domain of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{abc(a+b+c)}= \left( \frac{1}{ab} +\frac{1}{bc}+\frac{1}{ca} \right) \frac{1}{(a+b+c)^2}
\end{eqnarray*}
so by symmetry
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{a=1}^{\infty} \sum_{b=1}^{\infty} \sum_{c=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{abc(a+b+c)} = 3\sum_{a=1}^{\infty} \sum_{b=1}^{\infty} \sum_{c=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ab(a+b+c)^2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Similarly
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{ab}= \left( \frac{1}{a} +\frac{1}{b} \right) \frac{1}{(a+b)}
\end{eqnarray*}
so by symmetry
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{a=1}^{\infty} \sum_{b=1}^{\infty} \sum_{c=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{abc(a+b+c)} =6 \sum_{a=1}^{\infty} \sum_{b=1}^{\infty} \sum_{c=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a(a+b)(a+b+c)^2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
How to evaluate this sum in terms of $ \zeta(4)$ available on request.